# Facebook app with ssl certificate

Tags: facebook, ssl

Two weeks ago i bought a SSL Certificate for my domain. I have an app in Facebook and for Safari works fine but in Chrome the following message appears:

"Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Error desconocido."

I have set the "Secure Canvas URL" in the configuration of the app in Facebook.

What's the problem?

---

I have just checked it out in Internet Explorer and Firefox and works fine.

In both browsers enter the game directly.

With respect the Certificate and app settings, the certificate is valid for www and the domain, and in app setting i just typed the domain name.

---

Well, the function from Facebook that arise the problem is:

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
```

I hope this could be helpful.

Comment: as a test try a free cert from startssl.com and see if you get same error

Answer (score 2):

It is a known problem that Chrome handles this less elegant: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87957

But that does not take away the fact that it should work with a valid certificate. Can you checn with a few other browsers, like IE and Firefox? Please get back when those give any indication of the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens to me for my app, but only on Chrome on Ubuntu (Chrome on Windows 7 is fine, and Firefox [version 13 at the moment] on Ubuntu is fine), and it only happens when secure browsing is forced on in Facebook (Account settings > Security > Secure browsing).  By unchecking `Browse Facebook on a secure connection (https) when possible`, I no longer receive this problem.

Please downvote this answer (a lot, hahaha), because telling users to use a different operating system or to turn off secure browsing is not going to be received well!  I'll report back if I come up with a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the problem?

Your SSL cert is invalid or not configured properly. This can happen for example when you use your domain with www in app settings, while the cert is ussued on a domain without www, etc. It can be something else misconfigured also.

Answer (score 0):

I know it´s an old Thread but I just got a similar problem when facing some Free Hosts that uses shared SSL cert instead of Custom Domain Certs. On setting up your Canvas App, on "Secure Canvas URL", use the URL provided by the HOST instead of your custom URL.
Ex: If your host is openshift, they give an URL similar to -> php-blablabla.rhcloud.com. Use this one instead of blablabla.com (which would be the domain you paid for).
Hope this helps someone. 
Cheers.